# What vs Where ...is the common ground/basis

Tags: idioms, syntactic-analysis

According to Merriam-Webster the *common ground* is

> a basis of mutual interest or agreement

and the *basis* is

> the principal component of something

Both are often used in the context of being found (like a place). Wikipedia states that finding common ground is a technique for facilitating interpersonal relationships. Historically, it refers to the commons, which in many communities were a place which was available to everyone, such as the village pump, or the sidewalk of a road. Yet in her 1888 novel "Robert Elsmere" Mary Augusta wrote

> What common ground was there between him and any such exquisite youth?

I could find many examples for both *what* and *where* being used in questions asking for the *common ground* or the *basis*.

All four of these grammatical constructions are widely being used:

- What is the common ground for A and B?
- Where is the common ground for  A and B?
- What is the basis for X?
- Where is the basis for X?

Are all of them correct? Do the *what* versions differ in meaning from the *where* versions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless the *common ground* is really a place, I'd go for *what* since it specifies mutual elements of the two parties.

Comment: Yopu shouldn't overplay the significance of *principal component* in one specific definition of ***basis***, when that word also turns up in a definition of ***common ground***. Idiomatically it's quite normal to identify some relatively *peripheral* aspects/attitudes as "common ground" - they only need to be *common to (shared by) both A and B*. It's purely a stylistic preference whether you ask *what* or *where* any such common ground actually *is*.

Comment: Okay, so it's safe to say all versions are correct and do not differ in meaning, correct?

Comment: (1) Dictionaries don't give grammatical information, at least not willingly. (2) Whether you use _where_ referring to a metaphoric 'common ground', or whether you use _what_, depends on how seriously you're pushing the metaphor. It's perfectly acceptable to say _Where is the common ground here?_, but it's equally acceptable to say _What_ instead. There is no difference in meaning, nor in grammar, but the _`Mind` Is `Land`_ metaphor theme that licenses the _common ground_ metaphor will be strengthened. This may or may not be the effect you want, however.

Comment: @JohnLawler I get the feeling  though that *where* here gives the impression that the speaker thinks there isn't any common ground, whereas *what* might make us presuppose there is, depending on the context of course.

Comment: That's always a possibility, but normally the intonation makes it clear. In writing, of course, ...,

Answer (score 1):

It's a metaphor, and can be used with either what or where.  "What" is more common, I think.

Each has a different (potential) meaning:

"What is the common ground between A and B" is a more simple question, I think, but it assumes that there **is** common ground - there may not be.  You're asking the listener to describe it.

"Where is the common ground between A and B" could have the same meaning, and may be intended to mean that in many cases.  I think it carries less of an assumption that the common ground actually exists.  However, it could also have the following meanings:

- How do we get to the common ground?  Ie, how do we find out what it is?
- I expected there to be common ground, but I can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

"What" is asking for the nature or essence of the common ground, but "where" seems to ask the place or location (in reality or in a text) the nature or essence can be found.